# HTML 5 Canvas - Grid Block Fill-In

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a Canvas and have written out a grid(resembles graph paper) with the X & Y coordinates successfully.  What I'm looking to do now is the following:

-When someone clicks with a mouse a square in the grid will change to a different color
-Once a block is selected that data will not change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a separate 2D array that maintains the state for each (x, y) grid position.

When a click happens, check that state array to see if the cell was clicked before, and update the canvas as appropriate.

I created a little demo to show you: http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/xN45K/

Comment: Attached is the code I have currently.  I'm not sure yours will accomplish what I want.   http://jsfiddle.net/lank81/Yv3d4/

Comment: @MatthewLancaster you haven't done anything with the state array after you created it.  Look at my code _in detail_ and see how I query (and update) the state table on each click.  You don't have _have_ a click handler, yet.

Comment: Thanks for the Alnitak.  I changed things up just a tad but overall your solution got me going in the right direction.  http://jsfiddle.net/lank81/Yv3d4/5/